# Javascript variable assignment in nested for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

I am pulling my hair out with this algorithm. The goal is to take number array as an input and output a string that has all sequential numbers displayed as a range. For example if my input were [1,2,4,6,7,8,] my output should be "1-2,4,6-8". My issue lies with the variable assignment in my nested for loop's if statement. IndexEn is overridden each time j increments and should ultimately exit the inside loop as the highest value. The problem is that when I try to call the variable outside of the for loop it passes each value of IndexEn instead of the maximum. I don't understand how IndexEn is able to be outside of the scope of the inner loop while the inner loop is still running? Can someone please help me fix and understand whats happening here?

```js
function bkInd(arr){
    var bookSt="";
    var indexSt;
    var indexEn;
    for(var i =0;i<arr.length-1;i++){       
        if(arr[i+1] !== (arr[i]+1)) {
            if(i===0 || (i>0 && arr[i]) !== (arr[i-1]+1) ){
                bookSt+= arr[i]+",";
            }
        // check to see if number are sequential and SHOULD output starting index value - last value    
        }else{
            for(var j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
                    var count=0;    
                if(arr[j]==(arr[i +count]+1)){
                     indexSt = arr[i];
                     indexEn = arr[j];
                    count+=1;   
                }
            }
            //concatenate string 
            //console.log(indexEn); for value of index 
            bookSt+= indexSt+"-"+indexEn+",";
        }       
    }
    return bookSt;
}
var bookList = [1,3,4,5,7,9,10,11];
document.write(bkInd(bookList));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like nested looping (can be slow on large datasets) so I took a different approach, hope you don't mind:

```
var bkInd = function(arr) {
    var result = [];
    var seq = []; // 'Temporary' array

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        seq.push(arr[i])
        if(arr[i] + 1 !== arr[i + 1]) {
            result.push(seq.length > 1 ? seq[0] + '-' + seq.pop() : arr[i]);
            seq = [];
        }
    }
    return result.join(', ')
}
  // => '1, 3-5, 7, 9-11'
```

It instead 'builds up' a temporary array of numbers (`seq`) as it loops through `arr`. If the next number is sequential, `seq` keeps the last number and the loop continues. If the next number is more than one above the current one, `seq` is pushed to `result`, but if `seq` is more than one index long it will concatenate these to a hyphenated string. After `seq` get pushed, it gets reset to an empty array. Finally, it joins the `result` array with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Code is updated according to your requirement :

```js
function bkInd(arr){
    var bookSt="";
    var indexSt;
    var indexEn;
    for(var i =0;i<arr.length-1;i++){       
        if(arr[i+1] !== (arr[i]+1)) {
            if(i===0 || (i>0 && arr[i]) !== (arr[i-1]+1) ){
                bookSt+= arr[i]+",";
            }
        // check to see if number are sequential and SHOULD output starting index value - last value    
        }else{
         var count=1;
         indexSt = arr[i];
            for(var j=i;j<arr.length;j++){
                
                if(arr[j]==(indexSt+count)){
                    indexEn = arr[j];
                    count+=1;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            //concatenate string 
            //console.log(indexEn); for value of index 
            bookSt+= indexSt+"-"+indexEn+",";
        }       
    }
    return bookSt;
}
var bookList = [1,3,4,5,7,9,10,11];
console.log(bkInd(bookList));
```

Your inner for loop logic was incorrect. I have updated the code to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is the region of the code within which a variable is directly accessible.

In JS scope is defined by `function`s, blocks (i.e. `{` and `}`) for `let`, `const` and by `catch` blocks.

The following seems to work:

```js
function runnify(arr) {
    var runFrom;
    return arr.reduce((p,c,i)=>{
        if (c + 1 === arr[++i]) { // true if next item is sequential            
            if (runFrom == null ) { // We are at start of run                
                runFrom = c;
            }
            return p;
        }
        
        if (runFrom) { // We are at the end of a run            
            p.push(`${runFrom}-${c}`);
            runFrom = null;
            return p;
        }
        
        p.push(c); // Not sequential
        return p;        
    }, []).join(',');
}
var seq = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11];
document.write(runnify(seq));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could collect all items with a check, if consecutive in an array and join it at the end, for consecutive elements with a dash and the rest with comma.

```js
function consecutive(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a,i) {
        var last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (!i || last[last.length - 1] + 1 !== a) {
            r.push([a]);
        } else {
            last[1] = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (a) { return a.join('-'); }).join();
}

var array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11],
    grouped = consecutive(array);

console.log(grouped);
```